# Google fonts API issues

Tags: google-font-api

On my site URL I use google fonts API but it doesn't seem to be working at all? Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am completely clueless but if you need more info, please ask. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Edit: seems to have been a fault with my testing environment.
Thanks all who replied.

Comment: Works for me. What browser do you use?

Comment: It works for me and I'm using Chrome. Could it be your browser? Also, check to make sure you do not overwrite it anywhere else. Instead of using *{font-family: 'Rammetto One', cursive;}, I'd suggest using body {font-family: 'Rammetto One', cursive;} or html {font-family: 'Rammetto One', cursive;}

Comment: works in firefox, chrome and internet explorer

Comment: It's strange, I just got home and it works in the latest Firefox and IE but it didn't work on chrome or IE7. Well, I'll call it resolved for now, thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

some fonts just have to be totally integrated into api to work on all browsers

Comment: You should elaborate on what you mean by "totally integrated."